# Android Navigation Drawer fast closing and opening

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface, navigation-drawer

I implemented a `NavigationDrawer` using `ToolBar`. Everything is fine but now this drawer doesn't close smoothly so I decided to use `Handler` to close this drawer and changing Fragments using `FragmentTransaction` by calling through interface. But I'm not getting proper success. I'm posting some code also to get an appropriate answer.

```
public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
ll_contact_us.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((OnCloseDrawerListener) context).mCloseDrawer();
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    MainActivity.getInstance().displayView(4, 0, 0);
                }
            }, 200);
        }
    });

 public interface OnCloseDrawerListener {
    void mCloseDrawer();
}

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavDrawerListAdapter.OnCloseDrawerListener {
public void mCloseDrawer() {
    if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: 200 ms is very small time. You can try to increase this to 1000 or something that suits your needs better. May be that will help!!

Comment: 200 ms isn't the problem @John Can you please tell me the right way to create interface in adapter and close drawer of MainActivity?

Comment: Define a callback method in your Activity and call this function from your adapter.That should work.I hope you are aware of Callback interafaces in java.

Comment: Currently I get FatalException in the first line when I close drawer from Adapter. Will it work for also?